# hadoop insert performance vs database

Tags: hadoop, impala

I have 3 server and want to test hadoop performance.

**Is loading data into hadoop faster than to databases like cassandra** ?

and if I want use impala, does it slow down the data insertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is loading data into hadoop faster than to databases like casssandra ?

Generally yes. Loading files into Hadoop is simply a data copy operation. It's not directly comparable to a database upload.

Vanilla map-reduce is suitable for batch processing. Cassandra is fast, but it still needs to sort & replicate the incoming data. It's better to compare it with systems like hbase, kudu, scylladb, etc.

> and if I want use impala, does it slow down the data insertion?

Nope. Impala's data inserter (which called datasink) is of good quality in regards to disk IOs. And it uses HDFS' short circuit feature to reduce overheads. It should be faster than vanilla map-reduce in many data formats, specificly parquet.